# Вызов метода в другом потоке

Tags: c++, многопоточность

В моем классе существует метод, который должен вызвать другой свой же метод в другом потоке.
Компилятор такую ошибку выдает в строке **std::thread th(run);**

> error C3867: "Timer::run": нестандартный синтаксис; используйте "&", чтобы создать указатель на член

```
void Timer::start()
{
    std::thread th(run);
    th.detach();
}

void Timer::run()
{
    ...
}
```

реализация метода run на ошибку никак не влияет.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

В конструкторе потока надо передать аргументы функции, а у функций класса есть неявный аргумент - собствено объект класса, так что запишите

```
std::thread th(&Timer::run, this);   // сработало и в MSVC

// std::thread th(run, this);  // этот вариант сработал только на g++
```

З.Ы. Проверил сперва только на g++

Comment: *"Компиляторы C++ часто отличаются не самой понятной диагностикой ошибок"* - ага, поэтому не следует неправильно отвечать на вопросы, когда вы не знаете, чем конкретно вызвана та или иная ошибка.

Comment: *"этот вариант сработал только на g++"* Точно? У меня с дефолтными флагами нигде не работает.

Comment: Я на винде поставил Clion Nova, запустил cоздание проекта c дефолтными параметрами. И в нем сработало на g++, компилятор g++.exe (GCC) 13.1.0  В  CMakeLists.txt стоит set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17). Интересно, то, что сработало, это бага, или фича? ...  Но функции у меня были в кллассе, инлайновые.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло